# custom register action adding roles when registered

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

asp.net mvc 4 application using forms authentication. I'm trying to add roles to users when registered. I'm getting a error 500 from the server. so I put a break point on the register action. its jumping out on the Membership.CreateUser method, the username and password are ok. any ideas what could be wrong. and I know the if model state check shouldnt be there.

```
    public ActionResult Register(string username, string password)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            MembershipCreateStatus Status;
            Membership.CreateUser(username,password,null, null, null, true, null, out Status);
            //WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(username, password);
            if (Status == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
            {
                Roles.AddUserToRole(username, "Mechanic");
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(Status));
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Mechanics", "Mechanic");

        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put a try/catch around this method call and inspect the exception:

```
try
{
    Membership.CreateUser(username,password,null, null, null, true, null, out Status);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ... put the breakpoint here and inspect the exception
}
```